# htaccess more than 9 variables

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am having more than 9 params in my url to be mapped into particular php file. Url is

> http://abc.com/USA/NY/male/NY/all-status/all-religion/all-ethnicity/all-cast/all-professions/all-educations/recent_posted

and my htaccess rule is

> RewriteRule
>   ^USA/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
>   search.php?counrty=USA&state=$1&gender=$2&r_city=$3&r_mstatus=$4&r_religion=$5&r_ethnicity=$6&r_cast=$7&r_profession=$8&r_education=$9&sort_by=$10
>   [NC]

It is not working

Can please anybody sort out this issue? I need proper regex rule and URL

Comment: What's not working? No remap at all or wrong result?

Comment: If wrong result, I'll give you a free hint; `counrty` != `country`.

Comment: Use PHP to parse the URL, that’s way more convenient.

Comment: With something this long you're better not rewritting, it still looks long and messy. Just stick them in the query string like normal.

Comment: As far as I know, 9 is the maximum... maybe you could just not rewrite the search page? 

Comment: How should I modify url to use 9 mapped params and one query string

Comment: If one RewriteRule doesn't suffice, you can always split it up into two steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating such rule is restricted and bad practice & even worse that your passing the parameters to a search script; As your script progresses your most likely going to want other parameters passed other then USA, meaning your need a new rewrite for each route.

Really you should pass the entire url to your php script to handle the route.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This way you can `explode('/',$_GET['route'])` within your script, giving you an array of all your route parameters.

Comment: You can also look for some routing classes, that can do this and much more.

Answer (score 3):

Like Gumbo says, just send the whole lot to the page and process:

```
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    list($country, $state, $gender, [etc etc.]) = $segments;
```